# UILabel not expanding its height while using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

In my application I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains three `UILabel` and one custom Separator line as `UIView`.

The content of these three `UILabels` are fully `dynamic` and will be approx 3-4 Lines.

> My first two labels are working fine but my third label is not increasing its height. Here is my setup:

[image]

My Constraints are as Follows:

> First View:

```
  Leading to Superview - Trailing to SuperView- Top to Super View - Bottom To Second View - Height > 30

  First Label:
  Leading to First View - Trailing to First View - Top To First View - Bottom to First View - Height=20 -  Width
  First Label Discription Label
  Leading to First View - Trailing to First View - Top to First View - Bottom to First View - Height > 20
```

> Second View:

```
  Leading to Superview - Trailing to SuperView- Top to First View - Bottom To Third View - Height > 30

  Second Label:
  Leading to Second View - Trailing to Second View - Top To Second View - Bottom to Second View - Height=20 -  Width
  Second View Discription Label
  Leading to Second View - Trailing to Second View - Top to Second View - Bottom to Second View - Height > 20
```

> Third View:

```
  Leading to Superview - Trailing to SuperView- Top to Second View - Bottom To SeparatorView  - Height > 30

  Th Label:
  Leading to Second View - Trailing to Second View - Top To Third View - Bottom to Third View - Height=20 -  Width
  Third View Discription Label
  Leading to Third View - Trailing to Third View - Top to Third View - Bottom to Third View - Height > 20
```

> Separtaor View

```
        Leading to Super View - Super to Third View - Top to Third View - Bottom to  SuperView - Height =1
```

I am calling `-updateData()` in this method after updating i am caling `[self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];` .

All `UILabel`s have `numberOfLines` : 10

Here is output:

[image]

I have almost tried all possible ways like:

```
  [self updateConstraints];
    [self needsUpdateConstraints];
    [self setNeedsLayout]; and many more solutions available on SO.
```

But not able to make third Label Dynamic. Please Someone suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you set `numberOfLines` to 0 and set word wrapping?

Comment: @AaronBrager yes I also set `numberOfLines` to 0 and 10 none of these values works

Comment: You need to add a priority of 500 on the label's height. Then set content hugging and compression and resistance to defaultHigh

Comment: @Brandon just tried. Doesn't work for me :(